# how to find the default value of a select and an onchange

Tags: javascript

I have menu select with an `onchange` function
after the user has made his choice I would like to put the `onchange` and the select back to default

```js
function changeQte(element) {
  var qte = element.value;
  var t = $(element);
  var label = t.attr("aria-label");
  $("[data-nom='" + label + "']").attr("data-qte", qte);
  console.log($("[data-nom='" + label + "']").attr("data-qte", qte));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-select styleselect" aria-label="2001" onchange="changeQte(this);">
  <option selected value="1">1 sachet</option>
  <option value="2">2 sachets</option>
  <option value="3">3 sachets</option>
  <option value="4">4 sachets</option>
</select>
<a style="cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 5px; width: 90%" data-nom="2001" data-prix="1.10" data-qte="1" data-checkbox="2001" class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier">
    ajouter au panier
</a>
```

Comment: I think you should reset it like ```$(element).prop('selectedIndex', 0);```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work it says this
element is not defined

Comment: check it here https://jsfiddle.net/tp45/jp560zma/

Comment: is it possible to pass element.value in another function@tp45

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the value of `select` element on a variable and reuse at the end of `onchange` function.

```js
// Store default value
const defaultVal = $(".form-select").val()

function changeQte(element) {
  var qte = element.value
  var t = $(element)
  var label = t.attr("aria-label")
  $(`[data-nom=${label}]`).attr("data-qte", qte)
  console.log($(`[data-nom=${label}]`))

  // Passing value to another function
  anotherFunc(element.value)

  // Reset with default value
  element.value = defaultVal
}

function anotherFunc(val) {
  console.log("This value is from 'changeQte' func", val)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-select styleselect" aria-label="2001" onchange="changeQte(this);">
  <option selected value="1">1 sachet </option>
  <option value="2">2 sachets</option>
  <option value="3">3 sachets </option>
  <option value="4">4 sachets </option>
</select>
<a style="cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 5px;width: 90%;" data-nom="2001" data-prix="1.10" data-qte="1" data-checkbox="2001" class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier ">
                           ajouter au panier
                         </a>
```

Edit made according to OP's comment:

> is it possible to pass element.value in another function

Comment: is it possible to pass element.value in another function

Comment: Yes, you can put the `element.value` as parameter in the function you want to passed to